# IFrame object returning null when referenced from HTA containing the IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hta, peoplesoft

I am tryting to automate a repeated task of form filling using HTA. I am opeing the web page into an IFrame. the very First page is the Login page. I am ABLE to access the username and password elements of that page (Displayed in IFrame) easily, and hence able to autologin by clicking a button in HTA. But now, the next page contains a textbox, which i need to fill and then again click a button. Now, i have a button in HTA. When i click this button , i want that the text box should populate with the value i have provided. But instead, i get this error, Unable to set property 'value' of a null reference. On this displaying this object using an alert, it displays 'null'. I am not getting, why i am able to reference the elements on login page and why not on inside pages.

Below is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
 <HTA:APPLICATION
     APPLICATIONNAME="HTA"
     SYSMENU="YES"
     NAVIGABLE="YES"
>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">
    <title>HTA</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.resizeTo(700,700);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function Start() {
var iframePage = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument;
var userId = iframePage.getElementById("userid");
var passwd = iframePage.getElementById("pwd");
var form = iframePage.getElementById("login");
userId.value='uu';
passwd.value='pp';
form.submit();
}

function Show() { 
    document.getElementById("iframe").style.display = "block";
}

function FillRncntl() {
var iframePages = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument;;
var runcntl = iframePages.getElementById("PRCSMULTI");
runcntl.value='test';
}

</script>

</head>
 <body> 
        <form class="form" name="form">

                <input class="links" type="button"  value="Show PIA" onclick="Show();" /> 
                <input class="links" type="button"  value="Login" onclick="Start();" /> 
                <input class="links" type="button"  value="Enter Runcontrol" onclick="FillRncntl();" />
        </form> 
        <br>
        <div class="iframe" id="iframe" style="display:none">
        <iframe application="no" src="www.xyz.com" width="600" height="600" id="iframeid"> 
        </div>

 </body> 
 </html>
```

-Show PIA button shows login page . **Working Fine**.

-Login button is used to login automatically. **Working Fine**.

-Enter Runcntl button is used to fill some textbox. **NOT Working Fine**.

Its not only with this text box, i have same issues with other elemts from this page as well.

PS : Its a Peoplesoft Intranet Website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PeopleSoft content is contained within an iFrame itself so you need to grab the targetContent iFrame and search for the element in there.

The initial PeopleSoft login page is not displayed within an iFrame.

I changed the last element ID so that this will work on the component: PeopleTools->Process Scheduler->System Process Requests

```
function FillRncntl() {
   var iframePages = document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument;
   var targetContent = iframePages.getElementById("ptifrmtgtframe").contentDocument;
   var runcntl = targetContent.getElementById("PRCSRUNCNTL_RUN_CNTL_ID");
   runcntl.value='test';
}
```

Comment: Thats great @Darryls99 , it worked beautifully. I wasnt aware of the fact that Peoplesoft in itself is contained within an IFrame. However, i need to know one thing, about the iframe, "ptifrmtgtframe" , is this is a genric iFrame used by all the pages ? or different pages are displayed in different Iframes ? Where can i get this information. Thank you :-)

Comment: Short answer yes that iframe is used consistently across PeopleSoft AFAIK.  Long answer: By changing the url and based on the content type the iframe may or may not be present.  In the URL, look after the server name, if you change that from psp to psc, you will get the just the content within the iframe.  (no navigation).  Also there are other types of PeopleSoft content that may or may not be within an iframe (weblibcs, homepages, navigation, etc).  If found the name of iFrame by using the developer tools built into the browser to look at the page.

Comment: Thank you @Darryls99. But what about the pages that appear as floating pages, for example in case of, Process Schedular Request page, where we select the processes and server to run on. Is it also an IFrame ? how to refer its elements. Apologies if i am being nosy, can raise a new question if required. :-)

Comment: The floating pages are called modals and are in their own iFrame.  You can access them by something similar to this: iframePages.getElementById("ptModFrame_0").contentDocument.getElementById("PRCSRQSTDLG_WRK_SELECT_FLAG$14").checked=true

I strongly suspect that that iFrame name may change as is ends in a _0.  You need to use your developer tools to look at the page and find the path to these different items.  Also I did notice there are hidden inputs as well, I'm not sure what they are used for but they may or may not be relevant to what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you @Darryls99 for all the knowledge. :-)

Comment: Just fyi, i am trying to automate, running a process, just with a button click! :-)